# ExpressJS - make route accessible only from internal redirect

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I have an ExpressJS app with some routes that I don't want to work when typed into the url, they should work only when I redirect to them from my code.

Meaning, if an user types "myapp.com/url" it should not work. But if I add res.redirect("/url") in my code, it works

Comment: Why do you need this way solution? If this is a same service you can have internal methods. Do not expose API for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

basically you can't prevent a client from sending an HTTP request to an endpoint (you can't make it "not work"). Having said that your requirements aren't that different from a login logic using JWT.

You can use JWT to set which endpoints the client can gain access to. If the client is not permitted you will redirect him to a different page.

See: https://github.com/auth0/express-jwt

Update (see comments):
when submitting the form you should generate a UUID for the request. This UUID will be a token that represents a temporary resource (video).

This is how the API will look more or less.

1. `POST /submit`
2. `GET /generated/:UUID`
3. `GET /download/:UUID`

You will need to implement some logic that will manage this temporary resource.

Comment: The client should have access to the URLS, but only when redirected to it by my code. 
If the user clicks a button, it should redirect him to the page. But not if he types the url into search bar. Could I do that with this library?

Comment: You are confusing between frontend and backend logic. If you what to show a button if a user has the correct premonition to it you should use JWT. But you will have to have logic in your front end that will enable/disable the button.

Comment: Well the button should be enabled all the time. My app is basically this: There is a form where the user uploads a json file. If the json file is valid, a video gets created through a library.

Then the video is available for download.

It goes like this: / -> /submit -> /generate -> /download.

/submit is POST only, so that can't be accessed from the search bar already, but I want /generate and /download to be non accessible for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible as res.redirect (https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.redirect) accept the routes which are already available via URL. If you don't want to publish the route to the outside world, you might do some sort of authorization before displaying or sending data.